# Return all columns in anonymous linq join

Tags: c#, linq, join

How do I return all the columns in the following anonymous linq join:

```
var results = (from t in Table1.AsEnumerable() join t2 in Table2.AsEnumerable()
                on t.Field<string>("id") equals t2.Field<string>("id")
                into allcol from rows in allcol
                select rows);
```

I am getting allow rows from `Table2`, and no rows from `Table1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = (from t in Table1.AsEnumerable() 
                           join t2 in Table2.AsEnumerable()
                           on t.Field<string>("id")
                           equals t2.Field<string>("id")
                           into allcol
                           from rows in allcol
                           select new {table1=t,table2=rows});
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Does this return a single data set or two different datasets?  When i viewed this in the debugger, it seemed to separate them out?

Comment: yes you need to iterate through and convert them to specific type from anonymous type.